# Fun, tricky and hard questions for Unix/Linux Admin interview

Tags: linux, internet, administration, bsd

I am now preparing process of recrutation for group of Unix/Linux Administrators and I was wondering if maybe you have idea for fun or tricky or hard questions to ask the candidates in order to test their knowledge, level of system understanding and way of thinking?

I'd ask for fun questions (to lighten the atmosphere and for beginners), tricky questions (to induce thinking and for medium/high level admins) and hard ones (for highest level people, to find ninja administrators). Ideally, you might give the answer along with the question, but this is not entirely required ;)

So, any ideas?

Comment: Take a random question on this site.

Comment: Please don't cross-post on [three](http://serverfault.com/questions/291555/fun-tricky-and-hard-questions-for-unix-linux-admin-interview) [separate](http://superuser.com/questions/312057/fun-tricky-and-hard-questions-for-unix-linux-admin-interview) [sites](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16905/fun-tricky-and-hard-questions-for-unix-linux-admin-interview); see the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#crosspost)

Comment: Anything you ask should come out of YOUR knowledge. You can't just ask form questions and compare them against stock answers. If you know know what you are evaluating, us providing a list would not help much. Dig into the field yourself, find some real problems to that your employees will face, and listen to how they would tackle them. Evaluate based on their explanations. Ask them to demo their personal work environment, rc files, etc and explain what the bits are for.

Comment: Argh, I read 'ninja administrators' and suddenly stopped caring.

Answer (score 1):

Here's for the beginners to lighten up the atmosphere:

What is your favorite story from BOFH?

Comment: Yeah, except that real beginners gonna be all like "What's BOFH?" :D